# Data passing from AppComponent to another component which loads at a different time

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to call a service in the AppComponent to fetch some data, then i want to send it to another component which is loaded at another time. How can I ensure that the data can be captured in the other component? I want this setup to minimise the API calls as the same data which we are getting from the apis are reused at 2-3 places.

Comment: is your other component a child component of the first or a sibling? And you want to call a service... did you also create an injectable service?

Comment: it is child of child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to store the data in a globally Injectable service. In this service you should define a BehaviorSubject. See below.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  // Can subscribe to and emit events from a BehaviorSubject
  // BehaviorSubject can act like an event bus but will also return the last value in the stream upon subscription
  public userSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BehaviorSubject` in your service. 
When the later loaded component injects the service and subscribes to the `BehaviorSubject` it will immediately get the last emitted value.